# Count unique symbols per column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, unique

I was wondering how to calculate the number of unique symbols that occur in a single column in a dataframe. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'bbb', 'cc', ''], 'col2': ['ddd', 'eeeee', 'ff', 'ggggggg']})

df  col1    col2
0      a    ddd
1    bbb    eeeee
2     cc    ff
3           gggggg
```

It should calculate that col1 contains 3 unique symbols, and col2 contains 4 unique symbols.

My code so far (but this might be wrong):

```
unique_symbols = [0]*203
i = 0
for col in df.columns:
    observed_symbols = []
    df_temp = df[[col]]
    df_temp = df_temp.astype('str')

    #This part is where I am not so sure
    for index, row in df_temp.iterrows():
        pass

    if symbol not in observed_symbols:
        observed_symbols.append(symbol)
    unique_symbols[i] = len(observed_symbols)
    i += 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So to be clear if col3 was {col3: eee, rrr, ere} it would return 2?

Comment: That is correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.join` + `set` inside a *dict comprehension*
For problems like this, I'd prefer falling back to python, because it's so much faster.

```
{c : len(set(''.join(df[c]))) for c in df.columns}
```

```
{'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}
```

---

**Option 2**
`agg`
If you want to stay in pandas space.

```
df.agg(lambda x: set(''.join(x)), axis=0).str.len()
```

Or,

```
df.agg(lambda x: len(set(''.join(x))), axis=0)
```

```
col1    3
col2    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Doesn't `agg` normally have to be proceeded by a `groupby('')` call or something of a similar vein?

Comment: @akozi As per 0.20, [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) is a first order function.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
df.apply(lambda x: len(set(''.join(x.astype(str)))))

col1    3
col2    4
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe

```
df.sum().apply(set).str.len()
Out[673]: 
col1    3
col2    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
In [38]: df.applymap(lambda x: len(set(x))).sum()
Out[38]:
col1    3
col2    4
dtype: int64
```